# Laravel REST API countdown. Change a value in SQL after countdown passes

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I am working on a REST service in Laravel. I send from the mobile device a text, a boolean value (initially false) and set the countdown (in seconds) and store it in SQL database.

**For e.g: I send "abc", 30 (sec), false.**
How can I check if 30 seconds have passed and after that change automatically the boolean value from the database to true?

Comment: You would store a timestamp along with the duration in your database. Then have a cron job (artisan command) that comes along and checks to see if the time has elapsed and then cause an action to occur.

Comment: the duration should be of time data type? How is it best to send the duration from a mobile phone? calculate the nr of hours/mins/seconds or everything in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

use  sleep function 
for more refrence visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: but if we suppose the situation that I call the sleep function, and after that I delete the record from the database, what will happen?

Comment: well sleep function will put your php thread freeze for time you put and after that it will operate same.